# How to add id to a associate array

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to add an order_id to an existing set of arrays but cant figure it out.... its the same order_id that would get added to each array for upload into database
any help would be great
i have tried array_push but it only added the order_id and inserted into the database the first array

```
if(isset($_POST["part_no"]))

{
  $userid = $_POST["userid"];
  $order_info = array('user_id' => $userid);
  $db->insert('dwr_orders', $order_info);
  $order_id = $db->lastId();



    $part_no = $_POST["part_no"];
    $cab_no = $_POST["cab_no"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $width = $_POST["width"];
    $depth = $_POST["depth"];
    $height = $_POST["height"];
    $sku = $_POST["sku"];
    $notch = $_POST["notch"];
    $dwrlock = $_POST["dwrlock"];
    $cab_label = $_POST["cab_label"];


    for($count = 0; $count < count($part_no); $count++)

         {

          $fields = array (

            'part_no' => $part_no,
            'cab_no' => $cab_no,
            'description' => $description,
            'width' => $width,
            'depth' => $depth,
            'height' => $height,
            'sku' => $sku,
            'notch' => $notch,
            'dwrlock' => $dwrlock,
            'cab_label' => $cab_label,
            // 'order_id' => $order_id
          );

        }
          // $fieldx = array_push($fields, $order_id);

        }
$db->insert('dwr_dwrs', $fields);
 // $fieldx = array_push($fields, $orderid);
 // foreach ($fields['order_id'] = $order_id);


}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Also, judging from the code, you are only calling 'insert' once, regardless of 'order_id' being in there, so it would naturally only insert the values from the last iteration. Try placing your insert in the loop?

Comment: i do see i have an extra } above the insert but removing that as is there are not any errors and all arrays are inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so each value in the `POST` variables is an array? I assume this since you are using `count()` on `$_POST["part_no"]`. If so, I believe you want something more like this after you grab the new order id...

```
for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST['part_no']); $count++)
  $fields = array(
    'part_no' => $_POST['part_no'][$count],
    'cab_no' => $_POST['cab_no'][$count],
    // etc etc
    'order_id' => $order_id
  );
    
  $db->insert('dwr_dwrs', $fields);
}
```

it cycles through each part, and inserts to the db using the established $order_id

Comment: yes each value in POST is an array but when i add in order_id like you have above it only inserts the first array in db. the order_id is the same id i need to be added to each array. the POST array(s) are from a csv file

Comment: the code i posted should cycle through each item in the post arrays, and insert for each one. the code you posted on the other hand only has one insert and would only insert one record. did you put exactly as I put above after you get the order id? is order_id set as a unique field in your database? were there any errors?

Comment: yes i did finally get what you posted to work. thanks for all your help.